# Ubuntu newbie files question

Tags: files

Hi all,

I've installed Ubuntu desktop onto my n150 netbook.  It had 3 hard drive partions: C, D, and E.  I installed Ubuntu onto partition C and deleted Windows 7 on install.

Everything is working OK, but how can I access my files which were saved to drives D and E? They were photos, MP3s, etc, that I'd used previously with Windows 7.

Can anyone help me access these files?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you choose "Replace Windows" when installing Ubuntu? If yes, these data are gone. This option deletes the whole HDD.

Comment: Please edit your post with the output from running `cat /proc/partitions` from the Terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you've not formatted your entire hard drive?  By default Ubuntu shows the partitions for the disks available.  Windows formats your disk with NTFS and it is easily recognizable by Ubuntu.

Try checking for the size available for your Ubuntu.  It might be the size of your entire disk.

Comment: Also see bug #1073968: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1073968

Comment: I chose to replace windows thinking it would just format c and install to there it shows 2 other partitions now but there only 2gb each :( suppose I could try putting windows os back on see if there still there or have they gone ? ill be gutted if they have nightmare